# Anti-spam mod feature request

Tags: feature-request, moderation

Could a dev please think about creating a mod page that shows a list of top users who have 'http' in their answers please. I think this would help us find those who just link to their own pages and shouldn't be too complex to do, I don't think anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of thing can be done with the right query over on [data-explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), but my SQL-fu is too weak to come up with it myself. Once such a query has been identified, it should be easy to slap it into either mod-tools or /review.

Comment: There's *already* at least one query on data-explorer that does this; I used it a while ago to find a few spammy users.  If I get around to finding it again, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I imagine there is, it therefore would be less hard to just add as a mod tool page then.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds useful but might be too blunt an instrument -- A lot of valid/non-spam answers have links in them (I frequently link people to man pages, the O'Reilly page for "DNS and BIND", etc.).

Sorting users by "Percent of answers that contain a link" could be a good start.  "Percent of answers that contain the SAME link" would be better, but probably harder to code up in an efficient way (?).

Comment: It would be used as a search tool, not an auto-destroy button :)

Comment: I figured that, but we should strive for a clean tool (to whatever extent it's practical) - no sense having to wade through 20 screens of crap to find spammers :)